# Child Instantiate from parent class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, reflection, instance

It is possiable to instantiate child object from parent class without child class name.

For example, I have next classes:

```
public class A {
   protected int a;

   public A1() {
       a = 0;
   }

   public int getA() {
       return a;
   }

   public static A getObject() {
       // some code which I need to write
   }
}

public class A1 extends A {
    public A1() {
        a = 5;
    }
}

public class A2 extends A {
    public A2() {
        a = 10;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
A a = A1.getObject();
a.getA(); // return 5

a = A2.getObject();
a.getA(); // return 10

a = A.getObject();
a.getA(); // return 0
```

A1, A2 it is not all child classes. There are may be unlimited numbers.

How can I write getObject() method to it creates A class childs instanses.

**PS:**

*I just need to initialize child class object, but there are large amounts of child classes and I would not to call "new" for all of them and I would not to write static method to initialize it, also, all childs have same constructors. It is big lack that I can't create child instance from parent.*

Comment: If you don't know all the possible sub-classes at compile-time, then you need a way to figure that out at runtime. As it stands, it seems what you're asking for is a bit awkward. Could you provide a little more information about the problem you're having?

Comment: I just need to write superclass static method which will be invoke constructor of child class from which was called this static method. I think, that only way to realize it is call getStackTrace() ftom Thread and create instance using reflection. But it very complex way. May be I can realize it simply?

Comment: When you call A1.getObject(), no reference to A1 can be found in stack trace.

Comment: Alexei Kaigorodov, Я понял. И что, получается нет способов?

Comment: Nik, try to comment in english, please. It's easy for everyone to understand you. Future visitors could learn from your question easily this way.

Comment: @Nik: First, if getObject is not redefined in A1, then A1.getObject() is identical to A.getObject() in bytecode. Second, if you really want to generate objects of different types via A.getObject(), you have to inform this method of the desired type. Most natural way is to pass the desired class as an argument, just like Himanshu Moht recommended below.

Comment: Alexei Kaigorodov, Can I take caller class from thread stack if I override getObject() in A1 and A2 and call super.getObject()? I think I can. Or pass class to parent static method will be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `A a = A1.getObject()`,
you do use child classname (A1).
So a) your question is misleading and 
b) why can't you just write `A a = new A1()`?

If you want to write `A1.getObject()`, then you can redefine `getObject()` in class A1:

```
public class A1 extends A {
   public static A getObject() {
     return new A1();
   }

}
```

Without redefining, there is no way to declare `getObject()` in class A so that it return objects different classes because `A a = A1.getObject()` would compile to `A a = A.getObject()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
{
   protected int a;

   public A()
   {
       a = 0;
   }

   public int getA()
   {
       return a;
   }

   public static A getObject(Class c) throws Exception
   {
        A obj = (A)c.newInstance();
    return obj;     
   }
}

class A1 extends A
{
    public A1()
    {
        a = 5;
    }
}

class A2 extends A
{
    public A2()
    {
        a = 10;
    }
}
class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        A a = A1.getObject(A1.class);
        System.out.println(a.getA()); // return 5

        a = A2.getObject(A2.class);
        System.out.println(a.getA()); // return 10

        a = A.getObject(A.class);
        System.out.println(a.getA()); // return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use reflection to instantiate c?